# How to use float type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Can we use `Number` or is there something else type-specific? I used to go with `Number` and it seems to be working for me. `persent:Number = 1.01`...

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript (and by extension TypeScript) does not have specific types for integers and floats. There is only a `number` type. For really large numbers, we have [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

However, do note that the correct type to use for primitive values is all lowercase (`number` instead of `Number`, `string` instead of `String` etc.). `Number` is a TypeScript type for the object that wraps around a `number` primitive which provides additional methods.

Also, TypeScript can infer the type of a value when it is initialized. So `const myFloat = 1.01;` will be inferred as a `number`. If you can't provide a value when the variable is declared, then you can provide the type annotation like this:

```js
let myFloat: number;

// Somewhere later
myFloat = 1.01;
```